# how to choose qt lib version in python

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

when i run my python code,i have an error:

> AttributeError: 'QLineEdit' object has no attribute 'setPlaceholderText'

maybe this property was introduced in Qt 4.7. mine is 4.6
so i install another qt version 4.8.5
but when i use pyqt4,it still not work right.

> Python 2.7.5 (default, Nov 26 2013, 16:05:54)  [GCC 4.4.7 20120313
>   (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)] on linux2 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or
>   "license" for more information.

```
>>> from PyQt4 import QtCore
>>> QtCore.PYQT_VERSION_STR
>>>'4.9.5'
>>> QtCore.QT_VERSION_STR
>>> '4.6.2'
```

it was still 4.6.2,how can i choose version 4.8.5

Comment: You need to install PyQt4 for Qt 4.8.5. Download PyQt4 sources and compile it using `--qmake` configure parameter to specify where appropriate qmake binary file is stored.

Comment: I export LD_LIBRARY_PATH and QTPATH to qt4.8.5,and recompile PyQt4.it works well... Thanks.